# vim: about adding new rules to indentation configuration files

Tags: html, vim

in order to get correct indentation in my html5 files, I have added lines like this below to my `/usr/share/vim/vim73/indent/html.vim`:

```
call <SID>HtmlIndentPush('header')
```

As you can guess `header` is a new tag in html5..

Now I don't know if I should leave those lines in that file or create another file in `~/vim/indent/html.vim` that overwrites that `/usr/share/vim/vim73/indent/html.vim`.

What is your advice?

Take into account that I'm versioning my `~/.vim`.

Comment: Let me be the first one to shout the obligatory *never **EVER** touch the runtime files installed with your Vim!* There is never a reason to do so. Instead, put your mods in the `~/.vim/after` directory.

Comment: @glts thanks, but should I copy the `html.vim` file to `~/.vim/after` or is there anyway to "append" the new lines?

Comment: I wrote up an answer, but now I see that you are calling a private function in the `html.vim` indent script. You can't do that from outside the script. Better tell us what you are actually trying to achieve. – Have you read `:h html-indenting`?

Comment: @glts Im just trying to get correct indentation for new html5 tags. I dont get any help when I run that, just `Sorry, no help for html-indenting`

Comment: Ok, seems like it's a new help topic, I'm running Vim 7.4 ... and by the way Vim 7.4 doesn't have that internal function `s:HtmlIndentPush` any more – that's why it's bad to rely on internal (script-local, to be precise) functions.

Comment: @glts should I install 7.4? that would solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using Vim 7.3.

Vim 7.4, which is the current "stable" (in quotes) release, has had its support for HTML improved. I checked the indent script and I can see that it does have code for new HTML5 tags, including `header`.

You could try upgrading your Vim to 7.4 and your problem will probably simply disappear.